# AWS CodePipeline Action execution failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to hook my GitHub repo with S3 so every time there's a commit, AWS CodePipeline will deploy the `./<path>/public` folder to a specified `S3 bucket`.

So far in my pipeline, the `Source` works (hooked to GitHub and picks up new commits) but the  `Deploy` failed because: `Action execution failed
BundleType must be either YAML or JSON`.

This is how I set them up:

#### CodePipeline

- Action name: Source
- Action provider: GitHub
- Repository: *account/repo*
- Branch: master
- GitHub webhooks

#### CodeDeploy

- Compute type: AWS Lambda
- Service role: myRole
- Deployment settings: CodeDeployDefault.LambdaAllAtOnce

#### IAM Role: myRole

- AWS Service
- Choose the service that will use this role: Lambda / CodeDeploy
- Select your use case: CodeDeploy
- Policies: AWSCodeDeployRole

I understand that there must be a `buildspec.yml` file in the root folder. I've tried using a few files I could find but they don't seem to work. What did I do wrong or how should I edit the `buildspec` file to do what I want?

> Update

Thanks to @Milan Cermak. I understand I need to do:

CodePipeline:

- Stage 1: Source: hook with GitHub repo. This one is working.
- Stage 2: Build: use CodeBuild to grab only the wanted folder using a `buildspec.yml` file in the root folder of the repo.
- Stage 3: Deploy: use

```
Action Provider: S3
Input Artifacts: OutputArtifacts (result of stage 2).
Bucket: the bucket that hosts the static website.
```

CodePipeline works. However, the output contains only files (.html) not folders nested inside the public folder.

I've checked [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-name-storage) and figured how to remove path of a nested folder with `discard-paths: yes` but I'm unable to get all the sub-folders inside the `./<path>/public` folder. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use CodeDeploy, as that's a service for automation of deployments of applications, but rather CodeBuild, which executes commands and prepares the deployment artifact for further use in the pipeline.

These commands are in the`buildspec.yml` file (typically in the root directory of the repo, but it's configurable). For your use case, it won't be too complicated, as you're not compiling anything or running tests, etc.

Try this as a starting point:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - ls

artifacts:
  files:
    - public/*
```

The `phases` section is required, that's why it's included (at least, thanks to the `ls` command, you'll see what files are present in the CodeBuild environment), but it's not interesting for your case. What is interesting is the `artifacts` section. That's where you define what is the output of the CodeBuild phase, i.e. what gets passed further to the next step in the pipeline.

Depending on how you want to have the files structured (for example, do you want to have the `public` directory also in the artifact or do you only want to have the files themselves, without the parent dir), you might want to use other configuration that's possible in the `artifacts` section. See the [buildspec reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html) for details.

Remember to use the output artifact of the CodeBuild step as the input artifact of the Deploy to S3 step.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your answer but it looks like it's about building the code for further use. My goal is to push the `public` folder which is already in the repo to an S3.

Comment: Yes, you understood that part correctly. CodeBuild is a bit of an overkill, but since you want to push only the `public` directory to S3, you have to "repackage" the artifact that's coming from the Source step (your git repo) to the Deploy step (the S3 deploy action). That's what CodeBuild does here; the `artifacts` section defines what files go into the output artifact of the Build step. One thing I missed tho - as the next step in the pipeline, you ought to have the S3 Deploy (as was suggested here and also in your other SO quesiton).

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you're suggesting. I think I'm getting close to it. Still doesn't do what I expect. I'm going to update my question.

Comment: If you want *everything*, even diving into the subdirectories of `public`, try using `public/**/*` in the buildspec.yml. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: It does and I've tried that. The problem is it threw all files in the subfolders into the root of the S3 bucket. That broke the links to assets, css and such. I'm trying to keep the tree of the `public` folder.

Comment: Don't use the `discard-paths: yes` then. That should keep the folder structure intact.

Comment: Sorry. I confused you. I'm trying to push a nested `public` folder so I need discard-paths. Otherwise, it will just throw the folder with its path to the s3 bucket, that leads to the `index.html` remain in a nested folder, not in the root of the bucket.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187761/discussion-between-milan-cermak-and-viet).

Answer (score 3):

CodeBuild use buildspec, but CodeDeploy use appspec.

Is there any appspec file?

Comment: Thank you @t_yamo No, I forgot to include it. In my case, what it should look like? I've checked here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html#appspec-reference-lambda
But it seems like even if I "deploy" the build folder, I need to put the files in an S3 bucket. I need to specify it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Buildspec is for CodeBuild as t_yamo pointed out.

You are using CodeDeploy which uses an appspec.yml file, which looks something like this for my config.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /path/to/destination
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: /UnzipResourceBundle.sh
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: /RestartServer.sh
      timeout: 3600
```

UnzipResourceBundle.sh is just a bash script which can be used to do any number of things.

```
#!/bin/bash
// Do something
```

You can find a sample for the AppSpec.yml file from Amazon Documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-example.html#appspec-file-example-lambda

Answer (score 0):

CodePipeline recently announced a deploy to S3 action: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/01/aws-codepipeline-now-supports-deploying-to-amazon-s3/

Comment: I've read that one. It's for Code Commit, not straight from GitHub.

Comment: @Viet the S3 deploy action will work with any supported source action (including GitHub).

Comment: @TimB Thank you. Doing so will deploy everything inside my repo to the s3, not just the folder I want, right?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to configure the S3 deploy action to partially deploy an artifact (i.e. select a folder). It sounds like you need a build step (minimally create a new artifact from the folder you'd like to deploy - a build step is also a good place to do other things like Typescript compilation, Webpack, Hugo/Jekyll generate, etc.)